# How many numbers with $5$ odd digits are divisible by $125$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How many five-digit numbers can be formed using only odd digits such that the number is divisible by $125$?

Comment: What did you try??

Comment: When is a number divisible by $125$? If you don't know check first few number divisible by $125$ and deduce the pattern.

Comment: when it has 5 as its unit digit @kingW3

Comment: @CoderSingh Is $115$ divisible by $125$?

Comment: Ummm...sorry. I was wrong @kingW3

Comment: I started counting from 10000 @SEWillB but it took a lot of time

Comment: "I started counting..." is not a mathematical method. You must **think** and abstract the problem... as much as it is possible.

Comment: Just write them out and count ...

Comment: @JeanMarie you sound like a category theorist :)

Comment: @SEWillB I appreciate your remark about the max. abstraction :)

Answer (score 3):

We must clearly be a multiple of $5$ so we end in a $5$ or $0$. Then the only using odd digits condition gives that we must end in a $5$.

We must be a multiple of $25$ ending in $5$ so we must end with $25$ or $75$. Odd digits condition then gives that we end with $75$.

Then we are a multiple of $125$ ending with $75$. So we can end with $375$ or $875$. Again, odd number condition gives that we must have last three digits $375$.

Now, $125\mid1000$ so any number with digits $ab375$ in decimal is a multiple of $125$. Odd number condition then gives $a, b \in \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$. And we can have any such combination, and each distinct combination clearly gives a distinct number...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give a proof using congruences notations and properties (this proof will be very parallel to the proof of @SEWillB.)

Let I= { $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ }.

Let $n=\overline{abcde}$ with $a, b, c, d, e \in I$ the decimal representation we are looking for. It means that:

$$\tag{1}n=a.10000+b.1000+c.100+d.10+e$$

The condition of divisibility by 125 is expressed so:

$$\tag{2}n \equiv 0 \  \pmod{125} $$

$$ \iff c.100+d.10+e\equiv 0 \  \pmod{125} $$

because $1000$ and $100000$ are multiple of $125$.

$$\tag{3} \iff d.10+e \ \equiv 25.c \  \pmod{125} $$

because $100\equiv -25 \  \pmod{125}$.

Now let us enumerate the cases. There are few of them:

- if $c=1$, no values of $d , e \in I$ are possible.
- if $c=3$, we have to take $d=7$ and $e=5$.
- if $c=5$, the RHS is $0 \pmod{125}$ whereas the LHS cannot be $0$.
- if $c=7$, (1) $\iff d.10+e \ \equiv 50 \  \pmod{125} $ which is possible for no value $d, e \in I.$
- if $c=9$, (1) $\iff d.10+e \ \equiv 100 \  \pmod{125} $ which is possible for no value $d, e \in I.$

Thus, the solutions are:

$$\overline{abcde}=\overline{ab375}\ \text{for any} \ a, b \in I\text{,  yielding 25 solutions.}$$

Comment: I believe that there is a mistake in the final bullet point here; if $c=9$ then $25c \equiv 100 \pmod{125}$ and we don't get solutions. Note that as it stands $ab975$ isn't a multiple of $125$!

Comment: @SEWillB You are perfectly right. I forgot to check ! I correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $1000$ is a multiple of $125$, an integer is divisible by $125$ if and only if the integer expressed by its last three digits is a multiple of $125$. So you need an odd multiple of $125$ that is less than $1000$. Those are $125,$ $375$, $625,$ and $875.$ The only one that contains no even digits is $375$. Those must therefor be the last three digits. The first two can be any of the five odd digits, so you have $5\times5$ choices.